# PlayerPrefs in Unity not changing correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sort of new to Unity, so please don't be annoyed if you think that this isn't enough code, or an extremely simple mistake. So, I have a button, it says Autorestart. When I click it, it should turn from false to true. It does not. Here are screenshots and code. Thank you! Tell me if you need more code, but I don't think you do.

Before:

[image]

After clicking Autorestart: false, it should have turned to Autorestart: true

Here is some code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class manageautorestart : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text text;
    void Start(){
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("autorestart")) {
            text.text = "Autorestart: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString ("autorestart");
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("autorestart", "false");
            text.text = "Autorestart: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString ("autorestart");
        }
    }
    public void Change(){

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("autorestart") == "false") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("autorestart", "true");
        }
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("autorestart") == "true") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("autorestart", "false");
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("autorestart", "false");
        }

        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }
    void FixedUpdate(){
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        text.text = "Autorestart: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString ("autorestart");
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `Change()` ?

Comment: Take a look at your logic. If the value is "false" you set it to "true". So far so good, but... The next block unconditionally sets it to "false" on both code paths. You may want an `else if` and lose the last else.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this should be an answer ;) in general I would prefer to use `GetInt` and `SetInt` for storing a bool flag (0/1) instead of strings but maybe that's just a question of taste

Comment: FYI, you needn't call `PlayerPrefs.Save`, usually it is saved automatically.

Comment: Calling `PlayerPrefs.Save()` during fixed update is a strange idea. You should only call it after making a change.

Comment: I'm new to this playerprefs stuff, so sorry for bad code practice.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I'm sort of confused. Where are you saying this, in the Change function, or Start. If it is in the Change function, then what's wrong with setting it on and off from true and false? Or are you just saying to take the else statement off? I'm REALLY sorry if I sound like an idiot.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is the Start and FixedUpdate fine though?

Comment: Change is broken. Read the code. If it is false set it to true, then if it is true set it to false or set it to false. There's no way that function does not set the value to false.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ohhhhhh I see it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first choice would not be to use a string to store a boolean.

You could use :

```
public class manageautorestart : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text text;
    void Start()
    {
        SetText();
    }
    public void Change()
    {
        bool autorestart = GetAutorestart();
        // flip the value 
        autorestart = !autorestart;
        SetAutorestart(autorestart );
        SetText();
    }

    private bool GetAutorestart()
    {
        // Get stored value, 0 if none
        int temp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("autorestart", 0);
        // convert 0/1 to false/true
        autorestart = (temp == 1) ? true : false;
        return autorestart;
    }

    private void SetAutorestart(bool value)
    {
        // store it as int
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("autorestart", value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    private void SetText()
    {
        text.text = "Autorestart: " +  GetAutorestart();
    }
}
```

You now have three distinct methods to set/get the value and place it in the text. The Change method makes use of all three.

Comment: But may I ask whats wrong with my code, I still don't understand. Sorry

Comment: What's wrong with your code was the logic, first you check if false then set to true and next line you check if true then set to false. Meaning you started with false, went to true and back to false. If you start with true then it goes to false (skipping the first if statement to false). The else part is likely never to happen.